# Show dialog if the location of user is not turn on in place picker android

Tags: android, google-maps

I implemented Place Picker from Google API. It seems to work nice ,but I want it to show a dialog if the gps location of the device is not turned on and when user turns back after turning its location on, the map should automatically change to current location of device , like it works in Whatsapp.

```
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        try {
            startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity()), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if gps is enabled you should use

```
final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
    buildAlertMessageNoGps();
}
```

And to automatically update you gps location, you should use

```
manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, <min time>, <distance>, this);
```

- min time is the minimum time between two updates.
- distance is the minimum distance for apply update to location.

Android documentation is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener))